# Android - JSONArray to RecycleView Adapter?

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

In my Android app, I get a JSONArray of objects. Is it possible to pass this through directly into a recycleView adapter?

All of the recycleView implementations I've seen get JSONArray data first, and then loop through each object in the array, and transfer the values to a custom POJO(Plain old java object) and add it to a arrayList of the custom Java object, and then use this arrayList for the recycleView adapter.

However, it my app, I can potentially have many objects in the array. I believe it would be slow/inefficient to loop through it all in this fashion.

Is there anyway to pass the JSONArray directly into the recycleView adapter?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please show your attempts or errors when you tried

Comment: @JK140 please accept the answer as the solution if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. Just customize an adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private JSONArray array;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView property;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        property = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.some_view);

    }
}


public Adapter(JSONArray arr) {
    this.array = arr;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
    holder.property.setText(array.get(position).property);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return array.length();
}
}
```